# How to display a status beside a two battleship boards on python 3.4?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

I tried googling my question but I have no idea of how to word it so:
I am working on a game of battleship, coded in python 3.4.
So let's say I have two boards: the computer board and user board placed side by side. Then, I need to put status updates like computer/user hits, computer/user misses, and computer/user sunk. These are all easy to format until I get to the computer/user sunk. This portion of the status formatting is that not only do I have to display how many ships have been sunk, but I also have to list out the ship types that have been sunk.

For example, if the user hits a patrol ship and battleship, then under ships sunk for the user, it would look something like:

```
sample board                        Computer update       User update
A| | | | | |    ships hit:          0                     2
B| | | | | |    number of misses:   5                     10
C| | | | | |    ships sunk:         0                     2
D| | | | | |                                              Patrol ship
E| | | | | |                                              Battleship
F| | | | | |
```

Problem with displaying ships like that, is I am currently using for loops to create a string that adds a ship, and then a new line character like this:

```
 computerShipsSunken = ''  #the empty string
 for sunkenC in computersSunken:  
     shipNamesC = shipLetterToType[sunkenC]
     computerShipsSunken += '\n' + shipNamesC #the string that will use \n to create that neat format
```

So, the ships sunken will be listed out, and if I list it out each time, I dont want it to interfere with the board. I am reading up on string formatting but there isn't really anything about formatting things so they dont interfere with displays on the left?
Basically:
Is there any idea how I might be able to do this without messing up the boards?

Comment: Easy - determine if you need to print more than one ship name, print the first one and newline, print the next row of the board, then add appropriate string formatting to pad with the number of spaces needed to print the next ship's name. Repeat as necessary. Or, look into [`curses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html)

Comment: ok so I tried your way, and it technically would work, except I have to place the ship names in the order they are sunk. And the problem with that is that the computer ships(sizes as the value ex. Battleship: '4) is what helps create the list, computersSunken. And so when I try to create a list like this the order switches around.